# Run Firefox extension on window.open()

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Currently my Firefox add-on uses

```
require("sdk/tabs").on("ready", runScript);
```

to attach a script to the document (`tab.attach()`). But my target website opens a link as a new dialog window (minimal window with no tabs) and my add-on doesn't seem to run on it. How do I make it run on minimal window too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you either attach a script to a page when the user presses a button (using `tab.attach`), which means that the page has already loaded and you don't need to wait for a `ready` event. Or you attach your script to specific pages based on the URL, in which case you should be using a [pagemod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod) which waits for the page to be ready by default.

Comment: But the question is: "will pagemod work for dialog windows as well?"

Comment: It should. Do you know the dialog window's URL?